# How to use AssetPackager?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have tried different ways to use this AssetPackager. The software I am working with is already using it.

I am using notepad++ to modify the software. I am trying to change the javascript code but there is not any change. i suppose I am just changing the javascript files but I am not changing the base_packaged.js which is the one that all the pages use when they load the javascript files.

Could you please tell me what I need in order to update or create a new base_packaged.js with the changes I have made?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `rake` to update your assets:

```
% rake -T asset
rake asset:packager:build_all    # Merge and compress assets
rake asset:packager:create_yml   # Generate asset_packages.yml from existing assets
rake asset:packager:delete_all   # Delete all asset builds
```

In your development environment the assets are not packed if you use the `javascript_include_merged :base` helper in your view. This way you do not need to update it after every change.

You need to `build_all` before deploy production environment. When you use Capistrano for deployment there are tasks you can add to your deploy chain to get your assets updated on every deployment.

Comment: Thanks Arnep. It was very confusing. The thing is that I don't have Ruby on rails, so I was editing everything on notepad++ and then pushing it in Heroku with Git. I assume I need ruby on rails, then run rake on the console, the file base_packaged.js is going to be updated and then I can push it. Is taht correct?

Comment: Ya, I was assuming you were using rails due to the RoR-tag on your question :-) Best would be to install at least the framework to get full rails functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @arneps answer.

Use the rake tasks to update the assets locally but you then have to commit your packaged assets to Git and then repush your code to get it up on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks John. I think I need Ruby on Rails Installed to run the rake I asked Arnep. I have Windows so it is a nightmare. Is it mandatory or there is another way to run rake?

Comment: @luis vivas I am using Rail on Windows, not a big deal. Some things are slow (running tests), but everything else is running fine. Another idea would be to set up a virtual machine with Linux (eg. Virtual Box) for development.